# Как получить иконку процесса на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, icon

Имена процессов можно получить таким образом

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
   process_name = proc.name()
```

А как получить иконки тех же процессов?

Comment: что такое "иконка процесса"?

Comment: Под "иконкой процесса" я имею ввиду иконку программы, которой принадлежит этот процесс

Comment: Это поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810399/how-to-get-icon-icons-path-of-running-app-in-linux-windows

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень помогли